# Heroku doesn't find Firebase Database URL

Tags: python, firebase, heroku, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Heroku as sever with Firebase realtime database.

The below code is working on my computer **but not on Heroku.**

```py
...

cred = credentials.Certificate(JSON)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': os.environ["databaseURL"]
})
```

Heroku region is the US, and the firebase database region is east Asia. What happened here? Thanks.

#### Log

```
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791190+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791219+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/notice_bot.py", line 137, in <module>
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791342+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     runBot()
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791351+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/notice_bot.py", line 119, in runBot
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791436+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     previousNoticeIds = importPreviousNoticeIds()
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791439+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/notice_bot.py", line 67, in importPreviousNoticeIds
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791500+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     dir = db.reference().child(NOTICE_IDS_DB_PATH)
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791509+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 69, in reference
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791589+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     service = _utils.get_app_service(app, _DB_ATTRIBUTE, _DatabaseService)
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791599+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/_utils.py", line 101, in get_app_service
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791664+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     return app._get_service(name, initializer) # pylint: disable=protected-access
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791673+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/__init__.py", line 295, in _get_service
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791763+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     self._services[name] = initializer(self)
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791771+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 771, in __init__
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791955+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     _DatabaseService._parse_db_url(db_url)  # Just for validation.
2022-06-29T10:11:14.791956+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 837, in _parse_db_url
2022-06-29T10:11:14.792133+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     return cls._parse_emulator_url(parsed_url)
2022-06-29T10:11:14.792140+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py", line 863, in _parse_emulator_url
2022-06-29T10:11:14.792330+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]:     raise ValueError(
2022-06-29T10:11:14.792360+00:00 app[scheduler.6175]: ValueError: Invalid database URL: "https://MY_DATABASE_URL.REGION.firebasedatabase.app". Database URL must be a valid URL to a Firebase Realtime Database instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating another project that region setting is the US. I think the https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/514 issue is related.